# How do I create a TYPE TABLE in an SQL script?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to create a table type that I will pass as a parameter to a procedure. However, once I run the script once I start getting errors either claiming that the type doesn't exist, or that it can't be removed because the procedure needs it. Here is what I have got so far:

-- Create the type:

```
IF TYPE_ID('usr.NameList') IS NOT NULL DROP TYPE usr.NameList; -- Cannot drop type 'usr.NameList' because it is being referenced by object 'JWBestMatch'. There may be other objects that reference this type.
CREATE TYPE usr.NameList AS TABLE ([name] VARCHAR(MAX) NOT NULL);

-- delete the procedure if it already exists:
IF OBJECT_ID('TEMPDB..#JWBestMatch') IS NOT NULL DROP PROCEDURE #JWBestMatch;

-- create the procedure
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE #JWBestMatch -- Cannot find data type usr.NameList
    @name NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @referenceTable usr.NameList READONLY,
    @bestMatch NVARCHAR(MAX) OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN;
END;
GO
```

So how do you go about creating a type? In the docs I have read they just tell you literally how to create it, not how to actually create a script that doesn't fail after you run it once. What am I missing here?

Comment: Your stored procedure is in temdb and your type is in your current database. I don't think this is going to work. Create the stored procedure in the same DB as your type.

Comment: @zespri Ok, I'm still getting "Cannot drop type 'usr.NameList..." when I try to recreate the type though...

Comment: nvm I think it's working now...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you are trying to do:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('JWBestMatch') IS NOT NULL DROP PROCEDURE JWBestMatch;
GO

IF TYPE_ID('usr.NameList') IS NOT NULL DROP TYPE usr.NameList;
GO

CREATE TYPE usr.NameList AS TABLE ([name] VARCHAR(MAX) NOT NULL);


GO

CREATE PROCEDURE JWBestMatch
    @name NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @referenceTable usr.NameList READONLY,
    @bestMatch NVARCHAR(MAX) OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN;
END;
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

Not using the temp DB for the proc and not deleting the type every time seems to work:

```
IF TYPE_ID('usr.NameList') IS NULL CREATE TYPE usr.NameList AS TABLE ([name] VARCHAR(MAX) NOT NULL);

-- delete the procedure if it already exists:
IF OBJECT_ID('usr.JWBestMatch') IS NOT NULL DROP PROCEDURE usr.JWBestMatch;

-- create the procedure
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE usr.JWBestMatch
    @name NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @referenceTable usr.NameList READONLY,
    @bestMatch NVARCHAR(MAX) OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN;
END;
GO
```